# windows 10 - little black box keeps appearing with errors

Tags: windows-10

On windows 10. When i run one of my programs (as a developer) I'll get occasional errors on the command prompt - not because my code is bad, of course. Probably gnomes.

Anyway, whenever the gnomes get busy, I'll get like a BAZILLION little prompts from windows - the app runs on a server, and it prints the errors out. So I can *see* them, I don't need the notifications for this problem.

Nonetheless, windows will show each error in a small black pop-up on the bottom right - it animates with a "sliding in" so it is quite distracting. How can I stop windows from doing this, preferably for this one program, but I don't mind disabling it completely neither, you know?

Comment: Those "black boxes" are notifications. What do the errors say?

Comment: i dunno, whatever the error message is "blah blah blah cannot find blah blah blah", it is just a server error, nothing to do with windows. Can i turn these things off somehow?

Comment: First I need to know what kind of server/program you're using, I also need to know what it can't find.

Comment: um it's just a development tool that lets me drop apps into my phone without connecting via cable. When the app on the phone has an error (like, compile time) this message is relayed back to the server running on my laptop. the server program is called "ti shadow". what it cannot find is just a compile error and way beyond the scope of this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Hm.

Ok, i hit "start" and then wrote "notifications" - one of the options that pops up is "notifications & actions settings" - although windows team often seem to change the name, so good luck, stranger!

Anyway, when that box opens, there is an option called "show app notifications". Just uncheck that, and you should be good to go!

IDK how to target a specific app to block it, wish that were an option but you take what you can find, you know?